# Bitwise operation ~200

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Could you please explain step by step how ~200 becomes -201 in bitwise operation in Python.

200 in binary is

1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0

-201 in binary is:

-1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1

How that happened?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73038998/4902099.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative numbers are represented using the "two's complement" representation. This means that the binary representation of a negative number is the bitwise inverse.

For example, to find the two's complement representation of -201, we first convert 201 to binary, which is 11001001. Then, we take the bitwise inverse of this number by flipping each of the bits (i.e., changing 1s to 0s and 0s to 1s), which gives us 00110110. Finally, we add 1 to this number, which gives us 00110111. This is the binary representation of -201 in two's complement representation.

For example, bin(200) would return '0b11001000', and bin(-201) would return '-0b110111'.

Comment: Thank you, am i understood right.
In "~" operation you always add a bit at the beginning?
But flipping 200 in binary gives us 55 (00110111). Still doesn't quite get it.

Comment: Not necessarily. Each bit is inverted.